# multiple link list sort in java alphabetically

Tags: java, linked-list

I wanted some help with the multiple indexed linked list. I am trying to sort a set of names alphabetically and i don't even know how to start at all. I tried some of the code while searching in google but the case is i know how the code works but i don't where to put that code. so if you could help me i would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance....

This is my node class ....

```
    public class node {
    String data;long id;
    node next;



    public node(String data){
        this.data = data;
      this.id = getId(data);
    }



    public long getId(String line)
       {
          int i;
          long id=0;
          String s= null;
      char a;
      int j=2;
      for(i = 0;i <3;i++)
      {

         a = line.charAt(i);
         id += Character.getNumericValue(a) * Math.pow(26, j);
         j--;
      }
      return id;
   }

   public long getId()
   {
      return id;
   } 

   public String getData()
   {
      return data;
   }

   public void setData(String data)
   {
      this.data = data;
   }

   public node getNext()
   {
      return next;
   }

   public void setNext(node next)
   {
      this.next = next;
   }
}
```

This is my linked list class........

```
public class LinkedList {
    private node front;

    public void init(){
        front = null;
    }
    public node makeNode(String data){
        node newNode = new node(data);      
        return newNode;
    }

    public node findTail(node head){
        node current = front;
        while(current.next != null){
            current = current.next;
        }
        return current;
    }

   public node findSpot(String num) {
       node current = front;
       boolean searching = true, found = false;

       while((searching)&&(!found)) {
           if(current == null) {
               searching = false;
           }
           else if(current.data == num) {
               found = true;
           }
           else {
               current = current.next;
           }
       }
       return current;
   }

   public void deleteAfter(node spot) 
   { 
       node nextNode; 

       nextNode = spot.next; 
       spot.next = nextNode.next; 
   }

    public void addNodeAtEndOfList(String data){
        if(front == null){
            front = makeNode(data);
        }else{
            node tail;
            tail = findTail(front);
            tail.next = makeNode(data);
        }
    }

   public void addAfter(node spot, String data)
   {
    node newNode;

    newNode = makeNode(data);

    newNode.next = spot.next;
    spot.next = newNode;
   }

   public void addBefore(node spot, String data)
   {
      node newNode;
      if(front == null || spot.data == front.data){
            front = makeNode(data);
         front.next= spot;
        }
      else{
         newNode = makeNode(data);
         node tail = front;
         if(tail.next == spot)
         {
            tail.next = newNode;
            newNode.next = spot;
         }
         else{
            while((tail.next).next!= spot)
               tail= tail.next;

            tail.next = newNode;
            newNode.next = spot;
         }
      }
   }


   public void makeIndexList()
   {
    node spot;
    int currAlpha;

    indexNode AlphaIndex[26];


    /* Fill in the index array. */
    for (int j=0 ;j<26; j++) {
        currAlpha = j;
        AlphaIndex[j].weight = currAlpha;
        spot = findSpot(currAlpha);

        if (spot is equal to the front of the list) and
           (spot.weight > (currWeight + 10)) {
            weightIndex[j].firstOne = null;
        }
        else {
            weightIndex[j].firstOne = spot;
        }
    }
   }    


    public void showList(){
        node current = front;
      int i = 0;
        while(current != null){
            System.out.println("a["+i+"] = " + current.data);
            current = current.next;
         i++;
        }
    }
}

public class indexNode {
    int alpha;
    node firstOne;
}
```

this is my filein class..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class fileIn {
    String fname;
   LinkedList mylist = new LinkedList();
   node front;
   public fileIn() {
        //System.out.println("Constructor");
        getFileName();
        readFileContents();
      System.out.print(mylist.showList());
    }

    public void readFileContents()
    {
        boolean looping;
        DataInputStream in;
        String line;
        int j, len;
        char ch;

        /* Read input from file and process. */
        try {
            in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fname));
            looping = true;
            while(looping) {
                /* Get a line of input from the file. */
                if (null == (line = in.readLine())) {
                    looping = false;
                    /* Close and free up system resource. */
                    in.close();
                }
                else {
                    //System.out.println("line = "+ line);
                  mylist.addNodeAtEndOfList(line);
                    j = 0;
                    len = line.length();

                  /*for(j=0;j<len;j++){
                       //System.out.println("line["+j+"] = "+line.charAt(j));
                    }*/
                }
            } /* End while. */
             mylist.showList();

        } /* End try. */

        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error " + e);
        } /* End catch. */
    }

    public void getFileName()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter file name please.");
        fname = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You entered "+fname);

    }
}
```

Comment: Just to see whether I got you right: You're posting here hundreds of lines of java code and your question is how to create, compile and execute java programs in general and this one in specific. Right?

Comment: No! I just wanted to sort the linked list alphabetically and i don't know how to do it. I wanted to do it without using any linked list libraries functions.. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The get-the-job-done way to do this looks like this.

```
package org.jproggy;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Sorter {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(args[0])));
    String line;
    List<String> lines = new LinkedList<>();
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
      lines.add(line);
    }
    in.close();

    Collections.sort(lines, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    for (String val: lines) {
      System.out.println(val);
    }
  }
}
```

After compiling the class you can call it with

```
java org.jproggy.Sorter <path-to-file>
```

If you prefer to learn about building data structures or sorting algorithms you need to be more specific in what you want. But the sources of the JDK are available and there you can learn much how things are done well.
Btw. in java 8 it might even look like this:

```
    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(args[0]);
    BufferedReader data = Files.newBufferedReader(path);
    data.lines().sorted(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Nice.